# VSCode: embedded languages support for yaml?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a way or an extension if there is any for syntax highlighting in-file embedded codes in yaml files.

An example would be like this, see I have an other language embedded within the file in the content block.

````yaml
- header: my markdown post
  tags:
    date: 2021/6/28
  content: >+
    
    # my markdown contents 

    blah blah blah.

    ```
    blah blah blah.
    ```

    I need here to get highlighted
````

So in this case example above, I wanted to have a logic something like `highlight "level1" name of "content" blocks to the syntax highlight theme of the "markdown" language`.

Is there a simpler way to implement this using a built-in functionality, or an extension, or an already-exist boilerplate regexes for this or something?